# repository tag under distributionManagement vs repositories?

Tags: maven

I see `repository` tag under parent element i.e `distributionManagement` and `repositories`. What's the difference ?

```xml
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>...</id>
        <name>...</name>
        <url>...</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement> 

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>...</id>
        <name>...</name>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>...</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

My understanding  `repository` element under `distributionManagement` element specifies where it will deploy the artifacts at the time of deployment. It will come into picture only while `mvn deploy` i.e deployment time not during `mvn install` i.e build time. Right?

`repository` element under repositories element specifies from where dependencies needs to be picked up. It will come into picture only while `mvn install` not during `mvn deploy`. Right?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You have it exactly right!

From the [POM reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repository):

> Where as the `repositories` element specifies in the POM the location and manner in which Maven may download remote artifacts for use by the current project, `distributionManagement` specifies where (and how) this project will get to a remote repository when it is deployed. The repository elements will be used for snapshot distribution if the snapshotRepository is not defined.

- Repositories declared under the `distributionManagement` element will be used for deployment, i.e. when running `mvn deploy`.
- The `repositories` element will be used for downloading dependencies of the project. The command is not necessarily `mvn install` but any command that requires Maven to fetch artifacts from a repository.