# Maven can not resolve dependencies from private nexus

Tags: java, maven

We have recently set up our own private Nexus repository, but it seems that i have a problem downloading the jar files.
My pom looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>TestMvn</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>LB-RELEASE</id>
        <url>http://IP:8081/repository/data-RELEASE/</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>LB-SNAPSHOT</id>
        <url>http://IP:8081/repository/data-SNAPSHOT/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
<dependencies>

<dependency>
    <groupId>my.groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>my_artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1-RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and this is in my .m2/settings.xml file

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <servers>
     <server>
        <id>LB-RELEASE</id>
        <username>xxx</username>
        <password>xx</password>
     </server>

     <server>
        <id>LB-SNAPSHOT</id>
        <username>xxx</username>
        <password>xx</password>
     </server>
   </servers>
</settings>
```

So when I run `mvn clean install -U` I get
`Failed to execute goal on project TestMvn: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.example:TestMvn:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact my.groupId:my_artifact:jar:1.0.1-RELEASE in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)` So, it seems that maven doesn't connect to our private repo.
Strange thing is that it does create the appropriate folders under m2, but it only has 2 files

`my_artifact-1.0.1-RELEASE.jar` and `my_artifact-1.0.1-RELEASE.pom`.

Just to mention that I tried this on both Eclipse and InteliJ using both the Eclipse mvn and the terminal commands

any ideas why this is happening? thanks

Comment: That did it.Thanks. I was only given the code of <distributionManagement>. Why would you need the same information twice? anyway. thanks. did found that question on my own.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35317118/repository-tag-under-distributionmanagement-vs-repositories). It is not the same info twice.